# C# Azure Functions: Can't use CloudQueue type as output binding

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am creating a generic `WebHook` trigger function. A am trying to add output binding to the Azure Queue Storage. From the documentation, I see that `CloudQueue` type is supported for this output. But when I run the following code in the portal:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, CloudQueue outputQueueItem)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
}
```

it returns me an error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CloudQueue' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I run a new one webhook function that was published from Visual Studio with the following code:

```
namespace My.Azure.FunctionApp
{
    public static class SurveyWebHook
    {
        [FunctionName("SurveyWebHook")]
        public static async Task<object> Run([HttpTrigger(WebHookType = "genericJson")]HttpRequestMessage req,
           CloudQueue outputQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"Survey received");

            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
            {
                message = $"Survey received"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

it returns me an error:

> "'SurveyWebHook' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?"

How can I actually add `CloudQueue` type variable as output binding to my `WebHook` function?

**Update:**
When I use `IBinder` type:

```
namespace My.Azure.FunctionApp
{
    public static class SurveyWebHook
    {
        [FunctionName("SurveyWebHook")]
        public static async Task<object> Run([HttpTrigger(WebHookType = "genericJson")]HttpRequestMessage req, IBinder binder, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"Survey received");
            string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            CloudQueue outputQueue = await binder.BindAsync<CloudQueue>(new QueueAttribute("surveys"));
            await outputQueue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage("Test Message"));

            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
            {
                message = $"Survey received"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't return an error. But it also doesn't put a message to the queue.
The same happens when I use `[Queue("myqueue")] CloudQueue`.
It only works when I use `IAsyncCollector<T>`

**Update:**
Finally, I have understood why I didn't see messages in my queue. 
When I publish Azure Functions project from Visual Studio, it adds `"configurationSource": "attributes"` parameter to the `function.json`. And this is overrides my `connection` parameter in the output binding to the default storage account of my Function App service. And my queue was created in this default storage account. I have removed `configurationSource` parameter and my function started to work as expected.

Comment: Your binder example works just fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your first example work, fix the reference - add these lines on top:

```cs
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
```

To make your second example work, mark the `CloudQueue` parameter with `QueueAttribute`:

```cs
[FunctionName("SurveyWebHook")]
public static async Task<object> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(WebHookType = "genericJson")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [Queue("myqueue")] CloudQueue outputQueueItem, 
    TraceWriter log)
```

Comment: The first example still doesn't work (the same error). Maybe I should add a dependency in project.json.
The second example doesn't return error but the message is not added to the queue. The same when I use IBinder type. It only works if I use IAsyncCollector<T>

Comment: @Dmitry 1 - no need in `project.json`, should work as-is. 2 - then show your code, `outputQueueItem.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage("test"))` works fine.

Comment: @Dmitry Come on, you still don't have the `using`

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my inattention. It works now. Thanks.
But I still have strange issue with my code from VS.